# Want to transform position all nodes after a specific node in a d3 tree structure hierarchy

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have a d3 tree. Each node has an EntityType. If the EntityType of a specific node is equal to 'Battery', i'm setting the position of that a little further away from its parent than it usually is. The problem is that the node with EntityType 'Battery' also has children but their positions are not modified based on the position of this node.

Here is the code i modified.

```
.attr("transform", (d) => {
  if(d.data.EntityType === 'Battery') {
     return "translate(" + (d.y +100 ) + "," + (d.x) + ")";
  }
```

I used this line to modify the position of this node. But how do i modify the position of its children?

EDIT:

I have found that if i can check all the parents in the hierarchy of the node, i can set its position accordingly if there exists a node with EntityType Battery in its parent hierarchy.

But now i have to check complete parent hierarchy of a selected node. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. By setting the depth of the node and use the d3.descendants() property to set the depths of all of its children accordingly, we can achieve this.

And there is also a d3.ancestors() property to get all the ancestors of a node.